# php artisan route:list errorException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I get the following error when performing the following command `php artisan route: list`
[image]

I updated the RouteServiceProvider.php file. I am looking for the route admin.edit that does not detect it
May be is the wipe of a controller and create a new one, but I think that i did it correcly.

```php
$this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::middleware('web','auth')
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
        });
```

And the Routes File Admin.php:

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::resource('', [AdminController::class]);
```

With `php artisan route:list` another issue:

````php
   ErrorException 

  Array to string conversion

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\herminia-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar.php:416```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an array that should not be there ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers)):

```
Route::resource('', AdminController::class);
```